# Validating JSON request coming in via web-service, using a DTO/schema

Tags: java, json, validation

1. I have a DTO which maps to the data coming in via a JSON request through a REST webservice.
2. Also have a json schema according to which the client creates and sends the request.
3. I know how to implement custom validators and error handlers for an incoming xml request using both schema based and bean-validation. Trying to find something similar for json requests. Never worked with JSON before this.

Any pointers on how to start writing customized validators/error handlers for a json request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to validate the format of a JSON string object in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791027/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-the-format-of-a-json-string-object-in-java)

Comment: I am more concerned about data validation rather than plain format validation. Parser and parse exception will take care of the format problems.